# JSONata, how to transform array with elements missing?

Tags: node-red, jsonata

I am trying to convert an 2D array, let's say rows, into an array of the same rows, but for some rows one attribute is missing (omitted) and needs to be taken from one of the previous rows for which the attribute was filled.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to access the previous rows or to store the attribute in a variable that is persistent.

I hope somebody can give me a hint, how this is best achieved.

Let's assume the data looks like this:

```
{
  "payload": [
    {
      "Name": "Name1",
      "Values": "MsgId1.3 / Type1 / "
    },
    {
      "Values": "MsgId1.1 / Type3 / COMP"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Name2",
      "Values": "MsgId2.6 / Type1 / COMP"
    },
    {
      "Values": "MsgId2.5 / Type4 / COMP"
    },
    {
      "Values": "MsgId2.4 / Type4 / REJT"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Name3",
      "Values": "MsgId3.2 / Type7 / "
    }
  ]
}
```

The expected result looks like this:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "NAME": "Name1",
      "MSG_ID": "MsgId1.3",
      "MSG_TYPE": "Type1",
      "MSG_STATUS": ""
    },
    {
      "NAME": "Name1",   /* <-- this line is missing in my results */
      "MSG_ID": "MsgId1.1",
      "MSG_TYPE": "Type3",
      "MSG_STATUS": "COMP"
    },
    {
      "NAME": "Name2",
      "MSG_ID": "MsgId2.6",
      "MSG_TYPE": "Type1",
      "MSG_STATUS": "COMP"
    },
    {
      "NAME": "Name2",   /* <-- this line is missing in my results */
      "MSG_ID": "MsgId2.5",
      "MSG_TYPE": "Type4",
      "MSG_STATUS": "COMP"
    },
    {
      "NAME": "Name2",   /* <-- this line is missing in my results */
      "MSG_ID": "MsgId2.4",
      "MSG_TYPE": "Type4",
      "MSG_STATUS": "REJT"
    },
    {
      "NAME": "Name3",
      "MSG_ID": "MsgId3.2",
      "MSG_TYPE": "Type7",
      "MSG_STATUS": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

My last JSONata is like [this](https://stedi.link/7H2CXd3), but it does not work.

```
{
  "list": [
    $.payload
      .(
        $values := $.Values ~> $split(" / ");
        $name := ( ($.Name) ? ($.Name) : $name );
        {
          "NAME": $name,
          "MSG_ID": $values[0],
          "MSG_TYPE": $values[1],
          "MSG_STATUS": $values[2]
        }
      )
  ]
}
```

I also tried with $each() function, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Coleman's answer put me in the right direction.

My final solution can deal with large data sets. It runs quick even with thousands of objects in the payload array.

Example with solution can be found [here](https://stedi.link/8k1v4nS).

```
(
  $previous := function($index) {
    ($index > 0) ?
      ($.payload[$index - 1].Name ?
        $.payload[$index - 1].Name :
        $previous($index - 1)) : 
      "" };

  {
    "list": $
      .payload#$i
      .(
        $values := $.Values ~> $split(" / ");
        {
          "pos": (0) ? $i,
          "NAME": ($.Name) ? ($.Name) : $previous($i),
          "MSG_ID": $values[0],
          "MSG_TYPE": $values[1],
          "MSG_STATUS": $values[2]
        }
      )
  }
)
```

`.payload#$i` uses [Positional Variable Binding](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-positional-variable-binding) (`#$i`) to give me the index of the row of the original array `payload`.

`"NAME": ($.Name) ? ($.Name) : $previous($i),` checks if the `Name` is filled in the current row, if not a previous Name is searched via function `$previous`.

Function `$previous` checks if the `Name` of the previous row is filled and returns it. Otherwise it calls itself recursively until it finds the row above with `Name` filled.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't measured the performance of this solution, but one idea would be to accumulate the last used name in the accumulator of the `$reduce` function to fill in the blanks when populating the list: https://stedi.link/Uhi76Yq

Similar idea, but based on the `$index` argument passed down to the callback argument of the `$reduce` function: https://stedi.link/952AyV9 (maybe that one would be faster to run).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use the mapping operator (`.`) which has no defined order of execution, you need to write a recursive function to step through each row imperatively.  You can then pass in the `$name` from the previous row for use as the default name for the next row.  The following expression does this:

```
(
    $row := function($name, $payload) {(
        $first := $payload[0];
        $rest := $payload[[1..$count($payload)-1]];
        $values := $first.Values ~> $split(" / ");
        $name := ( ($first.Name) ? ($first.Name) : $name );
        [
            {
            "NAME": $name,
            "MSG_ID": $values[0],
            "MSG_TYPE": $values[1],
            "MSG_STATUS": $values[2]
            },
            $rest ? $row($name, $rest)
        ]
    )};
    {
        "list": $row("", payload)
    }
)
```

See https://try.jsonata.org/g7bcZKHKl

If your dataset is large enough, then this will eventually exceed the stack limit.  If this happens, you need to rewrite the function slightly to be tail recursive.  See https://docs.jsonata.org/programming#tail-call-optimization-tail-recursion

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It's performance is not great and I did not do the tail recursion thing, but while looking at it I saw the solution that works for large data sets as well. Using recursion only to find the name searching upwards: `$previous := function($index) { $.payload[$index - 1].Name ? $.payload[$index - 1].Name : $previous($index - 1) };` Will create a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found **a very inefficient** solution that seems to work by using the `$filter()` function.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, the runtime for everything with more than a few rows (I will have n-thousand) is minutes. So far it gives me the correct result, but that way I cannot use it.

`$names := ([$.payload#$i.({ "pos": $i, "name": $.Name })[name]])^(<pos);` filters the original data for all rows that have a name and stores the index = `"pos"` = `$i` with it.

`$prevname := $filter($names, function($v, $j, $a) { $v.pos <= $i })[-1].name;` filters the array `$names` for all rows with index <= current index (`$v.pos <= $i`) and only returns the last row's `.name`.

```
(
  $names := ([$.payload#$i.({ "pos": $i, "name": $.Name })[name]])^(<pos);
  {
    "list": [
      $
        .payload#$i
        .(
          $values := $.Values ~> $split(" / ");
          $prevname := $filter($names, function($v, $j, $a) { $v.pos <= $i })[-1].name;
          {
            "NAME": ($.Name) ? ($.Name) : $prevname,
            "MSG_ID": $values[0],
            "MSG_TYPE": $values[1],
            "MSG_STATUS": $values[2]
          }
        )
    ]
  }
)
```

Example with solution can be found [here](https://stedi.link/wEJWxhE).